# OpenLayers 3 hover to highlight only one specified object per time

Tags: javascript, hover, openlayers-3

**Original issue:**

OpenLayers 3 (tested also newest 3.14.1) should have some sense in the way it selects features that overlap each other. When `multi=false` it selects only one feature, but picks it quite randomly. When you hover over certain features from different directions, different feature is selected.

I have tried to tangle this by setting z-index to features to tell Openlayers the desired order. Indexing is set to order `point > line > polygon` but still I am not getting point selected first on hover.

Z-Index is applied to layer with:

```
rendererOptions: { zIndexing: true }
```

on layer and

```
zIndex: x
```

in style for different feature types.

***What happened first:***

*Z-indexing did not work so I was not able to tangle the situation for select. I kept `multi=true` and filtered results manually from list.*

*I had a function `getSelectedRemovableFeature(event.selected)` that took `event.selected` and returned only one feature out of it.*

*So, my selection had a code like follows:*

```
 var selectionInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
                               layers: [layersModule.getTargetLayer()],
                               condition: ol.events.condition.click,
                               multi: true
                            });  

and more..

selectionInteraction.on('select', function(event) {

                var selectedFeature = null;

                selectedFeature = getSelectedRemovableFeature(event.selected);

                if(selectedFeature){
                   .. some logic..
                   layersModule.getTargetLayer().getSource().removeFeature(selectedFeature);
                }
         });
```

***Then I got stucked:***

*I had*

```
var hoverInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
                       layers: [layersModule.getTargetLayer()],
                       condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
                       multi: true
                       });
```

*..and..*

```
hoverInteraction.on('select', function(event) {

            var selectedFeature = null;

            selectedFeature = getSelectedRemovableFeature(event.selected);

            // here I didn't know what to do..
            }
     });
```

*I had there a logic like this:*

```
  selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer);
  ...
  map.addControls([selectControl]);
 selectControl.activate();

  // unselect any specific feature...
  selectControl.unselect(vectorLayer.features[0]);
```

(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41017/how-can-i-unselect-a-feature-in-openlayers)

*.. but when it was there, no selections were removed, it worked like same as without this part.*

**Back to the origins:**

Now I realized, that tangling with the `hoverSelection` data is of no use, because new `multi=true` type event is thrown there before I could calculate how to select one only and show that. I believe that is the case, because nothing changes even I manually filter the results and remove features.

**In short finally:**

How to determine explicit order where the hover / select selection goes?

Comment: `layersModule.getTargetLayer().getSource().clear(); ` should remove all existing features within your layer. Did you try it? You also use `multi: true` during select interaction initialasation. Shouldnt this be `multi: false`? as long as you want to select only one feature at a time

Comment: Good point the multi false! Have to check it out back in work.

Comment: Multi = false makes it work. I have to just find out now why multi = true was used in code previously and if we still could use multi = false in both cases.

Comment: It turns out it is not possible now select objects hierarchigally (point first, then line, then polygon), because zIndexing is not working properly. That's why multi is true and selection based on the hierarchy is done manually. So, still in starting point: cannot select point below line and polygon, because different one is selected than desired. Any pointers how to get zindexing to work is appreciated.

Comment: Note that hit detection works in opposite rendering order: points are rendered last (by default), so they get hit detected (and selected) first. Also note that there are no `rendererOptions` like you state in your question. And finally, also note that you have full control of the rendering order not only by setting the `zIndex` property of `ol.style.Style`, but also by setting a `renderOrder` function on your `ol.layer.Vector`. That is an array sort function called with two features.

Comment: @ahocevar Please do post that as an answer, maybe with some more detail.This answer may be useful, that's why. (useful = candidate to gain bounty)

Comment: @ahocevar I tested now a removal of the whole zindexing from the features (there were much of it, really!) and now hover seems to work quite nicely. I will talk to our map expert about importance of the whole zindexing and if that solves the problem, I really do like to see your post as answer. It made the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that from some reason the draw styles included heavily z-indexing and what made this problem to occur was the following:

**Reason:**

From some historical reason selected style was forced on top by `zIndex: 100`. Normal selection had `zIndex: 1`.

That caused a problem: when you had point and line on top of each other and you select line, it's zIndex rose up to 100. That broke the natural highlight order, because 100 is far more than 1. Thus natural order, which @ahocevar pointed out, gets broken and highlighting becomes dependent of direction where you come near to the feature on map.

**Solution:**

I put selected and default style both to `zIndex: 1` and everything seemed to work ok event with that.

I will need to check still the reason of selected style on `zIndex` so high, but if there is no reason to continue its usage, this thing solves the problem.

**Side note:**

*Answer is a community wiki, because half of solution is from comment of another user.*

Answer (score 2):

Hit detection of features on a map works in opposite rendering order. By default, points are rendered last, so they get hit detected (and selected) first. When no `zIndex` is set on any style, the rendering order is polygons, lines, points, texts.

When you set `zIndex` on an `ol.style.Style`, you override this fixed rendering order, allowing you to e.g. render polygons on top of points.

Within these four groups (polygons, lines, points, texts), you can control the rendering order by setting a `renderOrder` function on your `ol.layer.Vector`. That is an array sort function called with two features:

```js
new ol.layer.Vector({
  renderOrder: function(a, b) {
    if (a.get('importance') < b.get('importance')) {
      return -1;
    } else if (b.get('importance') > a.get('importance')) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
});
```

The above assumes that your features have a numeric 'importance' property. Now when you hit detect (select) features of the same geometry type (e.g. points), those with a higher 'importance' value will be selected first, because they are rendered last.

Also note that there are no `rendererOptions` like you state in your question.